# Minimal width of line createable by different tiles with different spaces between tiles

Tags: least-common-multiple

We have **2 types** of tiles:

- type **A tile** has **width** of **70 cm** and the **space** between this type of tiles is **5 cm**,
- type **B tile** has **width** of **160 cm** and the **space** between this type of tiles is **3 cm**.

We put this tiles in a line like this (please note that there is "ending" space in the line):

- type A:

  - [space = 5 cm][tile = 70 cm][space = 5 cm][tile = 70 cm] … [space = 5 cm][tile = 70 cm][space = 5 cm]
- type B:

  - [space = 3 cm][tile = 160 cm][space = 3 cm][tile = 160 cm] … [space = 3 cm][tile = 160 cm][space = 3 cm]

---

What is the **minimal width** of the line that is able to be filled by both tiles of type A and tiles of type B?

---

I am able to solve this in the case where is no ending space in the line by looking for the **least common multiple** of blocks created from sum of space and tile (type A: 5 + 70, type B: 3 + 160. For the . But when I assume the ending space, it is more complicated.

Comment: $75 p + 5=163q +3$ this is a Diophantine equation, you can find on this site many ways to solve it.

Comment: Yes, that should be a Diophantine equation. Thank you!